# Lenovo Thinkpad T460 Multitouch not working

Tags: thinkpad, multi-touch

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on a Lenovo Thinkpad T460 and the touchpad doesn't support **multitouch**. Two-Finger gestures do. Am I missing dirvers?

Answer (score 0):

I've got a T460s and multi-touch gestures work, like pinch zooming in Google Maps, etc. on Ubuntu 16.10. Might be that this version's kernel supports the 460 hardware better. You can use a live DVD/USB to try it. (The kernel and the "X" server handling input devices of 16.10 will eventually appear in 16.04 as an LTS point release.)

Also, I've found installing the Touchpad-Indicator app helps. You can get it with:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:atareao/atareao
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install touchpad-indicator
```

Comment: Hi Nitai, I'm very glad to hear from you, I didn't expect any answer anymore, So I directly followed your advice!
However it did not work for me. Pinch zooming GM is only a two finger gesture. But do these [official multitouch features](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Multitouch) work on you machine as well?